# Is it acceptable to use "notably" at the beginning of a sentence to mean something along the lines of "interestingly" or "importantly"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I've been using "Notably" at in my own writing for quite a while now, as an alternative way to start sentences. But I'm not sure if it's actually grammatically acceptable. I haven't found any answers through Google or the site.

Here's an example:

> Notably, the new study finds that [...]

When using the transition, my intended meaning/interpretation is something of a cross between "Interestingly" and "Importantly". The second is too formal, in my opinion, but the first is limited to specific contexts where something is in fact *interesting*, as opposed to say "of notable quality." To me, it seems "Notably" strikes a good balance between the two.

**Question:** Is it grammatically acceptable to start a sentence with "Notably" as a transition?

Comment: Curiously, I'm pretty sure that you can use almost any such word . . .

Comment: It is *grammatically* acceptable, but consider (as a matter of style) whether it might be better to contrive for a point's notability to speak for itself.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: 'Significantly' sounds better, in my opinion, if you're not pointing out a prime example from many examples, or one of the most important of the various cases considered ('Non-statutory sites, notably the River Thames and tidal tributaries SMI, should also be considered and any appropriate avoidance or mitigation measures ...' {[Port of London Authority](https://www.pla.co.uk/Environment/Port-Operations)}). 'Notably' usually means 'in particular' when not immediately preceding an adjective.

Comment: Ah, yeah, "in particular" is probably the best match for what I mean when I use a bare "notably."

Comment: It needs prior context. However, we break text up into sentences and paragraphs which and often there is mandatory prior context One can create a problem by leaving out required context in any scenario. So the word seems fine at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notably**, the following usages demonstrate you can:

> **Notably**, it traced the upper Cavalla, proving that that river was not
>   connected either with the Nuon on the west or the Ko or Zo on the
>   east. [dictionary.com](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/notably)

and

> Most **notably**, Princess Diana's niece Lady Kitty Spencer, whose
>   father is Diana's brother, Earl Spencer.

Comment: But note that both of these demand prior context, with 'notably' a highlighting marker pointing out a prime example.